# select2 stop working for the cloned rows, why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

Select2 stopped working when I cloned new rows "drop down menu working
only for the first row (default one)" drop down menu for the cloned
ones not working. Here's my code:

```
**= f.inputs 'Items not in inventory' do
    %table
      %thead
        %td{style: 'width: 20%; padding-left: 20px;'}
          %b Select Product
        %td{style: 'max-width: 70px;'}
          %b Repossessed Inventory (Serial/Amount)

      %tbody{id: 'tableToModify'}
        %tr{id: 'rowToClone'}
          = semantic_fields_for :other_stuff do |os|
            %td{style: 'padding-left: 20px;'}
              = os.input :product_id, as: :select, label: false, collection: Product.all.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id), input_html: {class: 'select2'}
            %td
              = os.input :repossessed, label: false, input_html: { style: 'width: 100px;' }
              %td

                = link_to "x", "javascript:if ($('#tableToModify tr').length > 1) {document.getElementById('tableToModify').deleteRow($('#tableToModify tr').length - 1);}"

    = link_to 'Add item', 'javascript:cloneRow()'
    = f.input :rest_is_lost, as: :boolean, label: 'Mark unrepossessed items as lost', input_html: { checked: 'checked' }

  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit, label: 'Create Repossession Case'
    = f.action :cancel, label: 'Cancel', button_html: { href: url_for(action: :index) }, wrapper_html: { class: :cancel }

:javascript
  function cloneRow(){
    var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
    var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify");
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
    var numberOfRows = document.getElementById("tableToModify").rows.length;
    clone.id = numberOfRows + 1;
    table.appendChild(clone);
  }**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to destroy select2 before you clone the row and then bind it again:

```
function cloneRow(){
  var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
  var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify");

  $(table).find('select').select2('destroy');

  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  var numberOfRows = document.getElementById("tableToModify").rows.length;
  clone.id = numberOfRows + 1;
  table.appendChild(clone);

  $(table).find('select').select2();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the tip, but this is not working too , i try to get the element inside the input and bounded with the select2 but i fail many times. i don't know why!!!

Comment: it gives me this error : clone.getElementById is not a function

Comment: Use `console.log(clone)` to check what is `clone`.

Comment: its not defined {ReferenceError: clone is not defined}

Comment: So... you have not defined this variable... Could you show the part of code, wherein you try to call `clone.getElementById`?

Comment: yes sure, i call it here: (= link_to 'Add item', 'javascript:cloneRow()')

Comment: and here the id i call it: (%td{style: 'padding-left: 20px;', id: 'firstcell'}
              = os.input :product_id, as: :select, label: false, collection: Product.all.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id), input_html: {class: 'select2'})

Comment: and here is my function: (:javascript
  function cloneRow(){
    var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
    var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify");
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
    var numberOfRows = document.getElementById("tableToModify").rows.length;
    clone.id = numberOfRows + 1;
    table.appendChild(clone);
    clone.getElementById('firstcell')[0].select2();
  })

Comment: You can't call `getElementById` from `clone` object because this method is for `document` and doesn't exist for `clone`. You should use the part of code I attached to the answer above: `clone.getElementByTagName('select')[0].select2();`

Comment: i try it too but it gives me the same error: TypeError: clone.getElementByTagName is not a function    ReferenceError: clone is not defined

Comment: sorry if i bother, but its really wierd

Comment: Try this: `$(clone).find('select').select2();`. I've modified my answer too.

Comment: now it gives me just one error: (ReferenceError: clone is not defined)

Comment: drop down menu still not working with the cloned rows :(

Comment: Opss, I didn't understand you. My bad, sorry. I've corrected the answer. It should do the job :)

Comment: no worries i really appreciate your efforts, it was really kind and helpful but i think there is unknown error in the code. Thank you so much.